# How to pull values/strings from code behind into the .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all I have this code in code behind

```
       //a == the viewing month
       //b == the x or 1 which will be use to add or subtract depending on the action
       //c == the previous month
       //d == the next month
       int a = int.Parse(actual.Text);
       int b = int.Parse("1");
       int c;
       int d;

       c = a - b; //This provides the previous month for the link
       d = a + b; //This provides the next month for the link
```

Now on page load I want to pull the values for "c" and "d" into an anchor in my .aspx page. I've try numerous things but i can't get it right, is this even possible? if so how?

Thank you

Comment: I also just found another way, I provided the anchor a unique id and run it on the server side and i was able to provide the Href property there.

Comment: I hope you're not really using variables named a, b, c, and d in production code.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the numbers in the page you have to declare them as protected and make sure they are declared on the page not in your method. You can calculate them on page load or inside of the events called by the different controls you might have in your page.

Than in your .aspx page you can use

<%=c.ToString() %>

<%=d.ToString() %>

Answer (score 0):

You can add it on a label or textbox:

On Pageload

```
Label1.Text = c;
```

Comment: You may also want to consider a Literal if you go with this approach if you do not need to style the text itself. A Label will wrap your text in a span tag while the Literal will simply print the literal (hence the name) text assigned to it.